# passing vector to function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that subtracts 2 from each element of a vector, and whenever I pass a vector as a parameter to the function, it's outputting an error:

> Error in sub(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default.

so I have a vector that's called x1,
and my function call looks like that: sub(x1)

any help will be appreciated.

```
sub <- function(x)
{
   for(i in 1:length(x))
   {
      x[i] = x[i]-2
   }
   return(x)
}
```

Comment: How the object `x1` looks like. ... output from `str(x1)`. Untill now your example is not replicable.  BTW: your function is doing `x - 2`. The call `sub(1:4)` is working fine.

Comment: In addition to jogo's comment: try not to call your function `sub` as this name is already taken, see `?sub`.

Comment: Eventually you forgot to run your function definition ... !

Comment: There is no need for a loop or even a function, think "vectorized". E.g. `x <- 1:100`; x <- x - 2` does what you want

Answer (score 5):

In R a lot of function and operators (just a special form of functions) are vectorised. Vectorisation means that a function/operator works automatically on all elements of an vector (or vector like object).

Therefore, **our problem can be solved with much less code**. In addition using vectorised functions (especially basic stuff like `+`, `-`, ...) is much much much faster than looping over elements.

```
# define function that does subtraction
sub <- function(x){
  x - 2
} 

# define vector with numbers ranging from 1 to 20
my_vector <- 1:20 

# call function with my_vector as argument
sub(my_vector)
```

**In regard to your error:**

> Error in sub(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default.

It is telling you that you called a function `sub()` without providing an appropriate value for its argument `x`. Since you did not provide it, and there is no default, and it cannot find it otherwise R does not know what to do and signals (throws) an error.

**I can reproduce your error like so:**

```
# call sub without argument
sub()
## Error in sub() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

**I can prevent it by providing a value for argument `x`, like so:**

```
# call sub with value for x 
sub(1)
sub(x = 1)
```

**... Or I can provide defaults like this:**

```
# define function with default values
sub <- function(x = NULL){
  x - 2
}

# call new 'robust' sub() function without arguments
sub()
## numeric(0)
```

**... Or I can provide defaults like this:**

```
# define function with default values
sub <- function(x){
  if ( missing(x) ){
    x <- NULL
  }
  x - 2
}

# call new 'robust' sub() function without arguments
sub()
## numeric(0)
```

**Resources:**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4fMccWy5lU
- https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf
- http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html
- `` ?`function` ``
- https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you forgot to run your function definition:

```
sub2 <- function(x)
{
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  {
    x[i] = x[i]-2
  }
  return(x)
}
sub2(1:4) ## works fine

sub(1:4) ## Error calling the function sub(pattern, replacement, x, ...)
```

> Error in sub(1:4) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

or

```
> x1 <- 1:4
> sub(x1) ## Error
Error in sub(x1) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

If you would have choosen another name for your function (not a name of an existing R-function) the message is clear (to run in a new R-session):

```
# sub2 <- function(x)
# {
#   for(i in 1:length(x))
#   {
#     x[i] = x[i]-2
#   }
#   return(x)
# }
sub2(1:4)
# > sub2(1:4)
# Error in sub2(1:4) : could not find function "sub2"
```

I commented out the function definition to simulate *not running of the function definition*